# Unmet dependencies with unstable-desktop-full, Natty

Tags: ros, desktop-full, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I try to install ros-unstable-desktop-full on Natty 11.04, but I have next problem:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install ros-unstable-desktop-full
...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-unstable-desktop-full : Depends: ros-unstable-vision-opencv (= 1.6.1-s1313731650~natty) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-unstable-image-pipeline (= 1.5.2-s1313739013~natty) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-unstable-image-transport-plugins (= 1.4.1-s1313731752~natty) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
~$ sudo apt-get install ros-unstable-vision-opencv
...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-unstable-vision-opencv : Depends: libopencv2.3-dev (= 2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-1~natty) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

There was ros-electric previously, but I removed it completely.
How can I fix this problem? Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12758/unmet-dependencies-with-unstable-desktop-full,-natty/) by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 546 on 2012-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unstable is unstable; it is not guaranteed to work.

If you want the latest builds, you should look at the ros-shadow-fixed repository. It has more recent builds of things, but is even more likely to be broken.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) on 2012-01-25**:
I met this problem 2 month ago, so,  problem can be on my side. Thanks for reply.